# which function is used browser compatability testing in qtp

Tags: vbscript, automation, qtp

I want to know which function or which method is used for browser compatability testing.pls give some example

Answer (score 0):

There is no such facility in QTP to do browser compatability testing. You will have to build the scripts that work on different browsers yourself. However, it is extremely complex to do browser complexity testing.

Go for other tools like IBM Watchfire etc to be able to do some parts of browser compatability testing.